# Combining bytes while excluding MSb in MIPS

Tags: mips, midi

In MIPS Assembly language, how do I combine only the 7 rightmost bits of bytes? For example, if I have 1001 1100 and 0110 1100, combining them while disregarding their most significant bit would be (00)00 1110 0110 1100.

I need this for computing the actual delta time from an midi file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.text
LBU $t0, byte0
LBU $t1, byte1
ANDI $t0, 0x7f   # mask to 7 bits
ANDI $t1, 0x7f
SLL  $t1, $t1, 7
OR   $s0, $t1, $t0
.data
byte0: .byte 0x9c
byte1: .byte 0x6c
```